# Show again "log format is not recognized" - PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

While opening a .log file with PhpStorm the message "log format is not recognized." or something similar appeared, with a link to open the log pattern setting.

By mistake, I chose "hide this notification" or something similar - the rightmost option.

Therefore now the message doesn't appear anymore when opening a .log file with no recognized pattern.

I'd like restore the warming\message. How can I do it?

Comment: *"log format is not recognized."* That sounds like [ideolog plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9746-ideolog) to me. Do you have it? I'm not using it so cannot say where to click... but check your Settings/Preferences -- it will have a node for this plugin (`Editor | Log Highlighting (Ideolog)` AFAIK)

Comment: Yes, it is installed. Alas, in its settings there is no option to about "muted" notifications. Also, I've now tried to uninstall and reinstall hoping to reset its preferences, but the message still doesn't appear - I guess this preference is stored somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, if it's not in the GUI then it must be the raw config file (quite a few notifications/messages are doing that). What OS you are on? IDE Wide configs on Windows are typically stored in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2023.2` (for the current latest 2023.2 version). For Linux/Mac please check the following link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory .

Comment: Then check files in the `options` folder -- such a stuff should be in one of them (unless it's a per project settings and therefore will be stored in `PROJECT_ROOT/.idea` subfolder together with other project specific settings).

Comment: Did you had any luck locating that option? P.S. To check if it's saved as a  project specific option -- make a new project with just 1 log file (which format should not be recognized) and see if it will show that message there. I fit does then it's per project.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed your comments. I checked it's a global option, but I did not managed to find it into the `~/.config/` folder, it's a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Please contact the plugin author about that then: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog/issues -- they better know where they store such a setting.